# Sub-domain of sub-domain in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, subdomain

I am testing my rails app in staging server staging.example.com

I followed railscast #123.
I am using multiple Subdomain's  in my app.

I want to use the same app in production and staging.

How can i avoid staging.example.com in my staging server to detect 'staging' as a subdomain instead it should consider it as a domain.

because i have to test url like this

```
          staging              production
test1.staging.example.com  test1.example.com
test2.staging.example.com  test2.example.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Hi ashwin I ran into different issue but hope the following solution helps you, 

Have you tried changing tld_sizes provided, if not in your environment.rb paste the following code 

SubdomainFu.tld_sizes = { :development => 0,
                          :test => 0,
                          :production => 1 }

and when you set :test => 0, and check the current subdomain is will give you "test1.staging.example" as your subdomain name and when you set it to 1 it will give you "test1" as your subdomain.
```